# msbuild cannot find precompiled header

Tags: c++, msbuild, precompiled-headers

I have a `dll` which I build using `msbuild` with the command `msbuild dll.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug` and it depends on a static `lib`. My `lib` have `stdafx.h` and `stdafx.cpp` and they are in different folders.

I am using `/Yc` (create) for `stdafx.cpp` and `/Yu` (use) for the rest of the `lib`. However, I got the error - `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory [lib path.vcxproj]`.

In my project settings (Visual Studio 2017), both the `lib` and `dll` do include the paths to both the `stdafx.h` and `stdafx.cpp`. I tried to specify the path to create the precompiled header in the properties of `stdafx.cpp` but I got another error - `C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /Ycstdafx.h command-line option was not found in the source file stdafx.cpp`.

I've also tried to include using relative path (i.e. `#include "../path/stdafx.h"`) instead of just `#include "stdafx.h"` inside `stdafx.cpp` in `lib` but I got the same error.

Edit: Since my header and source files are separated into different folders, I've tried moving the `stdafx.h` into the folder of `stdafx.cpp` and now, the compiler is able to find `stdafx.h` but I have another error that my other `.h` files that are included in `stdafx.h` can't be found. This means that the issue will be solved if I merge my headers and source files into one folder but I want to keep them separated. Is there a way to specify the path of `stdafx.h` other than the methods that I've tried?

Comment: I recommend releasing your burden and not using precompiled headers.  Profile some builds using precompiled headers and profile without.  Subtract the two.  Is the savings worth all this hassle?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I didn't exactly profile but the difference with and without precompiled headers is pretty significant for my program. It takes about 10 to 20 seconds with and about 1 to 2 minutes without.